# Xamarin.Android MediaFile Store

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Mobile and I am able to launch and take a picture. The cannot seem to get the picture to save though. This is the code that Xamarin provides when using their Xamarin.Mobile component.

**How do I save the MediaFile file in Android?**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle    savedInstanceState)
    {
        var m_View = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Feed, null);

        btnCamera = m_View.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnCamera);
        btnGallery = m_View.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnGallery);

        btnCamera.Click += (sender, e) => {
            //launch gallery
            //allow photo editing/saving

            var mediaPicker = new MediaPicker (Activity);
            if (!mediaPicker.IsCameraAvailable){
            //Console.WriteLine ("No Camera!");
            }else {
                var intent = mediaPicker.GetTakePhotoUI (new StoreCameraMediaOptions {
                    Name = "test.jpg",
                    Directory = "APPNAME"
                });
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        };

        btnGallery.Click += (sender, e) => {
            //launch gallery
            //allow photo editing/saving

        };

        return m_View;
    }

    protected virtual async void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //user canceled
        if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
            return;

        MediaFile file = await data.GetMediaFileExtraAsync (Activity);

        file.Path


        //System.Console.WriteLine (file.Path);
    }
```

Comment: You can use OnActivityResult on MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permission added in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```